# Introducing correlations in the adjacency (or connectivity ) matrix

Tags: python, algorithm, matlab, probability, graph-algorithm

I am trying to build an adjacency matrix with correlation. i.e The probability of connection from node A to node B is set to a constant factor of order 1 (say α ), if node B is connected to node A. I need such a matrix to simulate neural network connectivity where nodes are neurons.

P(a→b|b→a = 1) = α  .... [1]

I though of the follow solution, but I am not sure it is correct

using Bayesian theorem and eq [1] as definition of α I can write :

P(b→a|a→b) = αP(a→b) / P(b→a)

Now all I need to do is generate 2 matrices with elements as independent random numbers. Then I divide them and multiply by α. Later I take care of the normalization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What is the correct method to generate such a adjacency matrix ?